# Jquery css function doesn't work in animate complete handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web

Here is the js code:

```
var index=0;
function reset(){
    for(var i=0;i<count+2;i++){
        $(imgs[i]).css("left",width*(i-1-index));
    }
}
reset();
//$(".dcCarousel").swipeleft(function(){
$("#left").click(function(){
    index = index+1;
    for(var i=0;i<count+2;i++){
        $(imgs[i]).animate({"left":width*(i-1-index)}, complete=function(){
            if(index>=count) {
                index = 0;
                //$(this).delay(0,reset);
                reset();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The first time reset is called, it is executed, the left attribute have been assigned correct values. But when I call it in animate()'s complete handler, the left attribute values are still like after animation. Why is this? And how to resolve this?

BTW, what I am implementing is a circular carousel. I clone the head and tail img and add them to the end and beginning of imgs, and I hope after scrolling to the end, and animation is over, I change the css attr to show the first img. Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Please don't suggest other carousel widgets, I need to write my own. Thanks!

Comment: Try: `$("#left").on('click', function(){`...

Comment: Remove `complete` in `complete=function(){`

Comment: 1.want a nice responsive carousel? use css3 and javascript. don'tuse jquery. 2.your animating in loop... lag.. in css3 u create a 3d container and just need to rotate/move that.

Comment: i don't know if jquery has some metods for animation chaining, but i think it can be because complete function, that should call reset, actually doesn't must be called last

Comment: Hey, where in your code are you defining count?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with that approach, but you'll probably get a smoother animation if you wrap your images in a container, and animate that. This simplifies your task, as at the end of the animation, you just have to pop the terminal image on the other end and shift the container to it's original position

Comment: The problem is solved. And great advice, Dom Day, animating a container instead of each img is way better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code, you will have many animations running, and the first to complete will try to reset the css while the other animations are running. The unfinished animations will overwrite the reset function changes.

to fix this, perhaps try something like

```
var animationCount = 0;
var index=0;
function reset(){
    for(var i=0;i<count+2;i++){
        $(imgs[i]).css("left",width*(i-1-index));
    }
}
reset();
$("#left").click(function(){
    index = index+1;
    animationCount = count + 2;
    for(var i=0;i<count+2;i++){
        $(imgs[i]).animate({"left":width*(i-1-index)}, complete=function(){
            if ( index >= count ) {
                animationCount -= 1;
                if ( animationCount == 1 ) {
                    index = 0;
                    reset();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, you are right about animations overwriting the reset values.Turns out only the first finished animation gets reset() called (it sets index to 0), but its changes are overwritten. I was so dumb not to see this... Thanks a lot!

Comment: np, I got the animation logic wrong though. just fixed it  ( i think )

Answer (score 0):

```
index = index+1;
    for(var i=0;i<count+2;i++){
```

must like this

```
for(var i=0;i<count+2;i++){
  index = index+1;
```